# Set a box with vagrant (virtualBox)

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

Based on the official [doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html), I've tried to install Vagrant with the " hashicorp/precise32" box.  I've added the box with :

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32
```

and change the configuration file :

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
```

When trying to start the virtual environement, I get :

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\vagrant_getting_started>vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

As suggested, I've opened the VirtualBox GUI and tried to manually start it:

[image: VirtualBox GUI for vagrant box]

Does someone know how to solve it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a known similar issue with latest VirtualBox version (4.3.14):

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615

I bet that you're running that version, if so downgrading to 4.3.12 should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm running 4.3.14... Thank you ! I try to downgrade now !

Comment: This has been fixed in newer versions (verified on 4.3.18).

Comment: Upgrading from 4.3.14 to 4.3.18 solved my problem. Thank you.